# Is it possible to get rendered text from textBlock

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, textblock

I have textBlock defined such that it fills the entire screen of the phone.

The textBlock is initialized with some data which cannot be displayed in the boundary and hence gets clipped.

I want to read the data which actually got rendered on the screen (i.e. whole data - clipped data).

Putting a breakpoint shows me that myNewTextBlock.Text contains the entire data that it was initialized with.

Thanks

Comment: Very interesting question, but I'm afraid that you can't. I might be wrong though.

Comment: Do you just need to set `TextWrapping="Wrap"` on the element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look at using [Measure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.measure%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) and [MeasureOverride](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.measureoverride%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) to determine how much of the `Text` would fit in the available space.

You'll likely need to test various trimmed versions of the `Text` but it shouldn't be too tricky.

Comment: Ohh..But I don't have the text beforehand. I get the text from some source and display it. Also, the amount of text displayed on screen would depend on the font size which can also differ in this case.

Comment: @abhinav in your question you say you want to know what was displayed but here you say you want to do it before you even have the text.? Yes this solution requires potenitally measuring the size of the text multiple times and yes you'll have to account for the font size.

Comment: Ok, let's forget for sometime what I said 'Now' :-). For the text that is displayed, wouldn't using Measure give me the size that is required by the text to be displayed. How would I get the text itself that is being shown on the screen? Am I missing something obvious here on using "Measure"?

Comment: @abhinav If you measure how much text could be displayed then you can infer that that is what is displayed.

Comment: Ohh...Okk..I get that...So, I think this is the best we have as of now :-)